# convert hdf5 files to tf.data datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hdf5

I want to convert multiple hdf5 files to a `tf.data.Dataset` via `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`.
Using:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filepath) #filepath:list containing all hdf5 filespaths
dataset = (dataset
    .shuffle(1024)
    .map(load_files, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    .cache()
    .repeat()
    .batch(BS)
    .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
)
```

I wrote the load_file method with a wrapper, since I cant use the `tf.io.read_file` and `tf.io.decode_png` which is normally used for i.e. images:

```
def load_file(file):
    hf = h5py.File(file.numpy(),'r')
    epsilon = np.array(hf.get('epsilon')) #array of (128,128,1)
    field = np.array(hf.get('field')) #array of (128,128,6)
    hf.close()
    return epsilon, field

def wrapper(file):
    e,f = tf.py_function(load_files, [file],(tf.float64,tf.float64))
    return e,f
```

Iterating through my dataset results in:

```
for e,f in dataset.take(5):
print(e[0][0][0], f[0][0][0])

tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float64) tf.Tensor(-2.815057100053552e-33, shape=(), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float64) tf.Tensor(-2.5008625074043214e-33, shape=(), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float64) tf.Tensor(1.352042249055261e-33, shape=(), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float64) tf.Tensor(8.932832186890058e-34, shape=(), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float64) tf.Tensor(-1.0549327174460344e-33, shape=(), dtype=float64)

for e in dataset.take(5):
print(e)

(<tf.Tensor: shape=(128, 128, 1), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[[1.],....), <tf.Tensor: shape=(128, 128, 6), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[[-2.81505710e-33,...)
```

However when I am trying to use to train my autoencoder:

```
m.fit(dataset, epochs=args.ep,callbacks = [tboard_callback])

Autodef getModel():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01), padding='same', input_shape=(128, 128, 1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01), padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01), padding='same'))


    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01), padding='same'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01), padding='same'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01), padding='same'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(6, (3, 3), activation='linear', padding='same'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')  #Using binary cross entropy loss. Try other losses.
    model.summary()
    return modelencoder:
```

I get the following error:

```
Epoch 1/3
2022-08-18 16:58:43.843892: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/forward_type_inference.cc:231] Type inference failed. This indicates an invalid graph that escaped type checking. Error message: INVALID_ARGUMENT: expected compatible input types, but input 1:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_BOOL
    }
  }
}
 is neither a subtype nor a supertype of the combined inputs preceding it:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_LEGACY_VARIANT
    }
  }
}

    while inferring type of node 'mean_squared_error/cond/output/_10'
2022-08-18 16:58:43.944734: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops_fused_impl.h:679 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: input must be 4-dimensional[128,128,1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lukas/Documents/ba-lukas/modelmain.py", line 154, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/lukas/Documents/ba-lukas/modelmain.py", line 116, in main
    m.fit(dataset, epochs=args.ep,callbacks = [tboard_callback])
  File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/home/lukas/Documents/ba-lukas/modelmain.py", line 154, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/lukas/Documents/ba-lukas/modelmain.py", line 116, in main
      m.fit(dataset, epochs=args.ep,callbacks = [tboard_callback])
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 889, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 490, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 458, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 596, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/lukas/anaconda3/envs/nano/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 269, in call
      outputs = tf.nn.bias_add(
Node: 'sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd'
input must be 4-dimensional[128,128,1]
     [[{{node sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1448]
```

Where could the mistake be? Why the input needs to be 4-dimensional? Thanks!
Tutorial I got the idea from is found here: [enter link description here](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/06/14/a-gentle-introduction-to-tf-data-with-tensorflow/#download-the-code)

Comment: This not a solution, just h5py tip: you can simplify `epsilon` statement to `epsilon = hf['epsilon'][()]` and same for `field`. The `[()]` tells h5py to return a numpy array of the entire data set and you can use `['name']` instead of `get('name')` to access the dataset. Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I totally forgot to call the batch() function on my dataset:

```
dataset =(dataset.map(pygen.wrapper, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().batch(args.bs).prefetch(AUTOTUNE))
```

Now I can train my model. Only a warning will appear:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/forward_type_inference.cc:231] Type inference failed. This indicates an invalid graph that escaped type checking. Error message: INVALID_ARGUMENT: expected compatible input types, but input 1:
    type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
    args {
      type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
      args {
        type_id: TFT_TENSOR
        args {
          type_id: TFT_BOOL
        }
      }
    }
     is neither a subtype nor a supertype of the combined inputs preceding it:
    type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
    args {
      type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
      args {
        type_id: TFT_TENSOR
        args {
          type_id: TFT_LEGACY_VARIANT
        }
      }
    }
    while inferring type of node 'mean_squared_error/cond/output/_10
```